# Pandas lookup from one of multiple columns, based on value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame:

```
Date    best    a    b    c    d
1990    a       5    4    7    2
1991    c       10   1    2    0
1992    d       2    1    4    12
1993    a       5    8    11   6
```

I would like to make a dataframe as follows:

```
Date    best    value   
1990    a       5
1991    c       2
1992    d       12
1993    a       5
```

So I am looking to find a value based on another row value by using column names. For instance, the value for 1990 in the second df should lookup "a" from the first df and the second row should lookup "c" (=2) from the first df.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 30):

There is a built in [`lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) function that can handle this type of situation (looks up by row/column).  I don't know how optimized it is, but may be faster than the apply solution.

```
In [9]: df['value'] = df.lookup(df.index, df['best'])

In [10]: df
Out[10]: 
   Date best   a  b   c   d  value
0  1990    a   5  4   7   2      5
1  1991    c  10  1   2   0      2
2  1992    d   2  1   4  12     12
3  1993    a   5  8  11   6      5
```

Comment: On the toy dataset apply takes 470us, lookup takes 531us

Comment: Hmm for some reason timeit gets a memory error when I try this on even a modest sized df of say 4000 rows, for 400 rows I get 8.17ms using apply and 3.05ms using lookup, so I expect lookup to scale better

Comment: Lookup might be preferrable due to the simpler syntax but both work perfectly, thx guys!

Comment: "Deprecated since version 1.2.0: use DataFrame.melt and DataFrame.loc instead."

Answer (score 9):

You create a lookup function and call `apply` on your dataframe row-wise, this isn't very efficient for large dfs though

```
In [245]:

def lookup(x):
    return x[x.best]
df['value'] = df.apply(lambda row: lookup(row), axis=1)
df
Out[245]:
   Date best   a  b   c   d  value
0  1990    a   5  4   7   2      5
1  1991    c  10  1   2   0      2
2  1992    d   2  1   4  12     12
3  1993    a   5  8  11   6      5
```

Comment: Any chance you could explain how this bit of code works?

Comment: @3kstc basically we use `apply` to iterate over the rows by passing arg `axis=1` so the lambda here is the row so for the first row `x` is the first row, we then return a specific column which in this case will be the value of `best` to index that row

Comment: Note, you don't need a lambda for a situation where the function takes a row and returns a value: df['value'] = df.apply(lookup, axis=1)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using `np.where` like below. I think it will be more efficient

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['1990', 'a', 5, 4, 7, 2], ['1991', 'c', 10, 1, 2, 0], ['1992', 'd', 2, 1, 4, 12], ['1993', 'a', 5, 8, 11, 6]], columns=('Date', 'best', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'))
arr = df.best.values

cols = df.columns[2:]
for col in cols:
    arr2 = df[col].values
    arr = np.where(arr==col, arr2, arr)

df.drop(columns=cols, inplace=True)
df["values"] = arr
df
```

**Result**

```
Date    best    values
0   1990    a   5
1   1991    c   2
2   1992    d   12
3   1993    a   5
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [looking up values by index column labels](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#looking-up-values-by-index-column-labels) because `DataFrame.lookup` is deprecated since version 1.2.0:

```
idx, cols = pd.factorize(df['best'])
df['value'] = df.reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx]
print (df)
   Date best   a  b   c   d  value
0  1990    a   5  4   7   2      5
1  1991    c  10  1   2   0      2
2  1992    d   2  1   4  12     12
3  1993    a   5  8  11   6      5
```

Answer (score 1):

[`lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) is deprecated since version 1.2.0. With [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) you can 'unpivot' columns to the row axis, where the column names are stored per default in column `variable` and their values in `value`. [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) returns only such rows where the columns `best` and `variable` are equal. [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) and [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) are used to match your requested format.

```
df_new = (
    df.melt(id_vars=['Date', 'best'], value_vars=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
    .query('best == variable')
    .drop('variable', axis=1)
    .sort_values('Date')
)
```

**Output:**

```
    Date    best    value
0   1990    a       5
9   1991    c       2
14  1992    d       12
3   1993    a       5
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution that uses a mapper dictionary:

```
vals = df[['a','b','c','d']].to_dict('list')
mapper = {k: vals[v][k] for k,v in zip(df.index, df['best'])}
df['value'] = df.index.map(mapper).to_numpy()
```

Output:

```
   Date best   a  b   c   d  value
0  1990    a   5  4   7   2      5
1  1991    c  10  1   2   0      2
2  1992    d   2  1   4  12     12
3  1993    a   5  8  11   6      5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look up a list of coordinates like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=['a', 'b', 'c'], columns=['x', 'y'], data=np.arange(0,6).reshape(3,2))

    x   y
a   0   1
b   2   3
c   4   5

coords = [('a', 'y'), ('b', 'x'), ('c', 'x')]
df.melt(var_name='column', ignore_index=False).set_index(['column'], append=True).loc[coords]
```