# How can I add a new column by referring to the value of another column in dataframe of pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have below a dataframe of pandas

```
df
index | ref |  1 |  2 |  3  |  4  |  5 |
1     |  1  | -3 | -2 | -9  |  0  | -2 | 
2     |  3  | -1 | -2 | -5  |  3  | -5 |
3     |  5  | -4 | -7 | -4  |  2  | -1 |
4     |  4  | -2 | -4 | -2  | -1  | -9 |
5     |  1  | -2 | -3 | -1  | -3  | -3 |
```

And I would like to make "new" column by referring values of "ref" column as below,

```
df
index | ref |  1 |  2 |  3  |  4  |  5 | new | 
1     |  1  | -3 | -2 | -9  |  0  | -2 |  -3 |
2     |  3  | -1 | -2 | -5  |  3  | -5 |  -5 |
3     |  5  | -4 | -7 | -4  |  2  | -1 |  -1 |
4     |  4  | -2 | -4 | -2  | -1  | -9 |  -1 |
5     |  1  | -2 | -3 | -1  | -3  | -3 |  -2 |
```

I had tried as following but I failed due to lack of memory. (something looping in code)

```
df['new'] = df[df['ref']]
```

Can you advice for me?

Answer (score 1):

Need [`DataFrame.lookup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html), but is necessary same types of columns and values in `ref` column:

```
#values are ints
print (df['ref'].tolist())
[1, 3, 5, 4]
print (df.columns.tolist())
['ref', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

```
#values are strings
print (df['ref'].tolist())
['1', '3', '5', '4']
print (df.columns.tolist())
['ref', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

---

```
df['new '] = df.lookup(df.index, df['ref'])
print (df)
       ref  1  2  3  4  5  new 
index                          
1        1 -3 -2 -9  0 -2    -3
2        3 -1 -2 -5  3 -5    -5
3        5 -4 -7 -4  2 -1    -1
4        4 -2 -4 -2 -1 -9    -1
```

EDIT:

If values in columns names are strings and values in `ref` are ints add [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) for convert:

```
print (df['ref'].tolist())
[1, 3, 5, 4]
print (df.columns.tolist())
['ref', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5']

df['new '] = df.lookup(df.index, df['ref'].astype(str))
print (df)
       ref  1  2  3  4  5  new 
index                          
1        1 -3 -2 -9  0 -2    -3
2        3 -1 -2 -5  3 -5    -5
3        5 -4 -7 -4  2 -1    -1
4        4 -2 -4 -2 -1 -9    -1
```

EDIT1:

There are duplicates in index or columns values.

```
print (df.columns.is_unique)
True
print (df.index.is_unique)
False
```

So need for unique index add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df['new '] = df.lookup(df.index, df['ref'].astype(str))
print (df)
   ref  1  2  3  4  5  new 
0    1 -3 -2 -9  0 -2    -3
1    3 -1 -2 -5  3 -5    -5
2    5 -4 -7 -4  2 -1    -1
3    4 -2 -4 -2 -1 -9    -1
4    1 -2 -3 -1 -3 -3    -2
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your advice! but I got error msg 
   pandas.core.indexes.base.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects. In ref columns, there are same values then I think it caused by this error.

Comment: I changed my dataframe from previous post

Comment: I think there are duplicates. Can you check `print (df.columns.is_unique)` and `print (df.index.is_unique)` ?

Comment: Hey, Jezrael, solved this issue! As your advice, I set the column names and values to same type and another post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25935431/pandas-lookup-based-on-value). Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following syntax. here parameter may be an expression as in multiply by 3

```
df['new'] = df['ref'] * <parameter>
```

for eg:

```
T['new'] = T['column0'] * 3
```