# Pandas dataframe column choosing value from other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, calculated-columns

Lots of similar queries already on here, but can't seem to find one that matches what I need. I have a pandas dataframe which primarily contains columns of contract names, and values with price data for a number of contracts.

```
df_yldchg.head(3)
Out[392]: 
ticker     RXH16 Comdty RXM16 Comdty RXU16 Comdty IKH16 Comdty IKM16 Comdty  \
field           PX_LAST      PX_LAST      PX_LAST      PX_LAST      PX_LAST   
date                                                                          
2016-01-04          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
2016-01-05     1.875658     1.960696     2.538501     4.386991     3.393998   
2016-01-06     4.596182     4.729410     5.814771     2.722861     2.102244   

ticker     IKU16 Comdty contract_month year     rolled_IK     rolled_RX  
field           PX_LAST                                                  
date                                                                     
2016-01-04          NaN              H   16  IKH16 Comdty  RXH16 Comdty  
2016-01-05     4.065628              H   16  IKH16 Comdty  RXH16 Comdty  
2016-01-06     2.523455              H   16  IKH16 Comdty  RXH16 Comdty
```

I am looking to add a column called e.g. 'RX_yldchange', which looks in column 'rolled_RX', matches it with a column header and takes the value from that column (same row).

The column names and data come from a database query and will be updated with new columns over time update, so I need the call to be compatible with checking all columns dynamically, rather than hardcoding. This would be akin to an 'index(Match())' call in excel, and I'm sure there is a simple way of doing it, but I have looked through a lot of questions on here without finding an answer.

EDIT2: I have already tried a lookup call that I found elsewhere here:

```
----> 1 df_yldchg['RX_yldchange'] = df_yldchg.lookup(df_yldchg.index, 
df_yldchg['rolled_RX'])

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in lookup(self, 
row_labels, col_labels)
   3474             result = np.empty(n, dtype='O')
   3475             for i, (r, c) in enumerate(zip(row_labels, col_labels)):
-> 3476                 result[i] = self._get_value(r, c)
   3477 
   3478         if is_object_dtype(result):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _get_value(self, index, 
col, takeable)
2530             return com._maybe_box_datetimelike(series._values[index])
2531 
-> 2532         series = self._get_item_cache(col)
2533         engine = self.index._engine
2534 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _get_item_cache(self, 
item)
2484         res = cache.get(item)
2485         if res is None:
-> 2486             values = self._data.get(item)
2487             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
2488             cache[item] = res

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in get(self, item, 
fastpath)
4124                         raise ValueError("cannot label index with a null 
key")
4125 
-> 4126             return self.iget(loc, fastpath=fastpath)
4127         else:
4128 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in iget(self, i, 
fastpath)
4141         Otherwise return as a ndarray
4142         """
-> 4143         block = self.blocks[self._blknos[i]]
4144         values = block.iget(self._blklocs[i])
4145         if not fastpath or not block._box_to_block_values or values.ndim 
!= 1:

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Is it possible that this would work if this wasn't a multiindex dataframe? I am happy to get rid of the second layer of column names ('PX_LAST') if that would help.

@screenpaver:

```
df_yldchg.columns

Out[413]: 
MultiIndex(levels=[['IKH16 Comdty', 'IKM16 Comdty', 'IKU16 Comdty', 'RXH16 
Comdty', 'RXM16 Comdty', 'RXU16 Comdty', 'contract_month', 'year', 
'rolled_IK', 'rolled_RX'], ['PX_LAST', '']],
           labels=[[3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1]],
           names=['ticker', 'field'])
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas lookup based on value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25935431/pandas-lookup-based-on-value)

Comment: `df['RX_yldchange'] = df.lookup(df.index, df.rolled_RX)`

Comment: Thank you - I actually tried this, but I get an error back - will edit OP to demonstrate.

Comment: What does df.columns print?

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't realize your DataFrame was named differently. Change it to `df_yldchg['RX_yldchange'] = df_yldchg.lookup(df_yldchg.index, df_yldchg['rolled_RX'])`. You need to reference the appropriate `DataFrame`, who knows what `df` is

Comment: Hey - thanks - sorry I tried that too. Tried both df_yldchg.rolled_RX and df_yldchg['rolled_RX']. (see edit above) - not sure what is going wrong here :(

Comment: @screenpaver - adding to original post now

Comment: @chmith Yes, `df_yldchg['RX_yldchange'] = df_yldchg.lookup(df_yldchg.index, df_yldchg.rolled_RX)` should work if you don't mind dropping the multiindex.