# Quickly convert Pandas Series of labels into Series of indirect values from corresponding columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following example dataframe:

```
N = np.arange(1, 10)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ref': [ 'a',  'b',  'c',  'd',  'c',  'b',  'a',  'b',  'c'],
    'a':   [   1,    2,    3,    4,    5,    6,    7,    8,    9],
    'b':   [  10,   20,   30,   40,   50,   60,   70,   80,   90],
    'c':   [ 100,  200,  300,  400,  500,  600,  700,  800,  900],
    'd':   [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000],
})
```

I want to "dereference" `ref` column in some way, to get this:

```
    'ref': [ 'a',  'b',  'c',  'd',  'c',  'b',  'a',  'b',  'c'],
    'ind': [   1,   20,  300, 4000,  500,   60,    7,   80,  900],
```

So each value in `ind` should correspond to the value in column labeled from `ref` at the same position.

Naïve approach would be to use something like `df[df['ref']]`, then multiply by identity matrix, then sum it column-wise. But because I have *quite large (~8 GB)* dataframe, doing this, I guess, would nearly square its size. And it just doesn't feel right.

Also due to the size just iterating over it is painfully slow. And I can't iterate with Cython, because converting this dataframe into numpy array loses label information, which I need to properly find the column.

Any suggestions?..

Comment: This is simple lookup: `df['ind'] = df.lookup(df.index, df['ref'])`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas lookup based on value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25935431/pandas-lookup-based-on-value)

Comment: Yeah `DataFrame.lookup` is an alternative but it has an inefficient loopy Python implementation.

Comment: `df['ind'] = df.apply(lambda x: x[x['ref']], axis=1)`

Comment: Yes true, @ayhan it's basically `[df.get_value(row, col) for row, col in zip(row_labels, col_labels)]`, see [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.25.1/pandas/core/frame.py#L3779-L3832)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it using `DataFrame.mask` or numpy where like below looks like numpy where performs slightly better in this dataset

```py
N = np.arange(1, 10)
df_b = pd.DataFrame({
    'ref': [ 'a',  'b',  'c',  'd',  'c',  'b',  'a',  'b',  'c'],
    'a':   [   1,    2,    3,    4,    5,    6,    7,    8,    9],
    'b':   [  10,   20,   30,   40,   50,   60,   70,   80,   90],
    'c':   [ 100,  200,  300,  400,  500,  600,  700,  800,  900],
    'd':   [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000],
})

df_b
```

**Using Pandas Where**

```py
%%timeit
df = df_b.copy()
cols = df.columns[1:]
df["ind"] = df["ref"]

for col in cols:
    df.ind.mask(df.ind==col, df[col], inplace=True)
df
## 6.73 ms ± 129 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

**Using Numpy's Where**

```py
%%timeit
df = df_b.copy()
arr = df.ref.values

cols = df.columns[1:]
for col in cols:
    arr2 = df[col].values
    arr = np.where(arr==col, arr2, arr)

df["ind"] = arr
df

## 1.21 ms ± 73 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

**Result**

```
    ref a   b   c   d   ind
0   a   1   10  100 1000    1
1   b   2   20  200 2000    20
2   c   3   30  300 3000    300
3   d   4   40  400 4000    4000
4   c   5   50  500 5000    500
5   b   6   60  600 6000    60
6   a   7   70  700 7000    7
7   b   8   80  800 8000    80
8   c   9   90  900 9000    900
```

Comment: I had modified your `.mask` solution to use `df['ref']==col` directly, as there is a large chance of value clash between labels and items. It's the most performant solution (8.86 sec per 100'000'000 items), as opposed to .apply (~2000 seconds). Thank you!

Comment: Okay, you have edited your answer with numpy solution, which is faster according to your benchmark. I will check it as well. Thank you again!

Comment: Checked, np.where is 3.64s per loop (100kk items).

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas.lookup()

```
df['ind'] = df.lookup(df.index, df['ref'])

  ref  a   b    c     d   ind
0   a  1  10  100  1000     1
1   b  2  20  200  2000    20
2   c  3  30  300  3000   300
3   d  4  40  400  4000  4000
4   c  5  50  500  5000   500
5   b  6  60  600  6000    60
6   a  7  70  700  7000     7
7   b  8  80  800  8000    80
8   c  9  90  900  9000   900
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use numpy indexing:

```
lookup = dict(zip(df.columns, range(len(df.columns))))
result = pd.DataFrame({ 'ref' : df.ref, 'ind': df.values[np.arange(len(df)), df.ref.map(lookup)] })

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
  ref   ind
0   a     1
1   b    20
2   c   300
3   d  4000
4   c   500
5   b    60
6   a     7
7   b    80
8   c   900
```