# Pandas: Find unique values from columns to calculate probabilities

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataset (circa. 200,000 rows x 30 columns) as a CSV. I need to use pandas to pre-process this data. I have included a dummy dataset below to help visualise the problem.

```
data = {'Batsman':['Tom', 'Nick', 'Nick', 'Nick', 'Tom', 'Nick', 'Nick', 'Pete', 'Pete'],
            'Outcome':[1, 0, 1, 'Wide', 'Out', 4, 1, 2, 0],
            'Bowler':['Bill', 'Bill', 'Bill', 'Bill', 'Bill', 'Bill', 'Bill', 'Ben', 'Ben']
    }
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df
```

The goal is to have individual columns that show the probability of each outcome for a batsman & bowler. By way of an example from the dummy dataset, Tom would have a 50% chance of an outcome of '1' or 'Out'

This is calculated by:

1. Batsman column - The total number of rows with batsman 'X';
2. Outcome column - The total number of outcomes with 'X';
3. Point 2. / Point 1. to determine the probability of each outcome;
4. Repeat the above to determine the Bowler probabilities

The final dataframe from the dummy data should look similar to:

```
data = {'Batsman':['Tom', 'Nick', 'Nick', 'Nick', 'Tom', 'Nick', 'Nick', 'Pete', 'Pete'],
        'zero_prob_bat':[0,0.4,0.4,0.4,0,0.4,0.4,0.5,0.5],
        'one_prob_bat':[0.5,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.5,0.4,0.4,0,0],
        'two_prob_bat':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.5,0.5],
        'three_prob_bat':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        'four_prob_bat':[0,0.2,0.2,0.2,0,0.2,0.2,0,0],
        'six_prob_bat':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        'out_prob_bat':[0.5,0,0,0,0.5,0,0,0,0],
        'Bowler':['Bill', 'Bill', 'Bill', 'Bill', 'Bill', 'Bill', 'Bill', 'Ben', 'Ben'],
        'zero_prob_bowl':[0.1428,0.1428,0.1428,0.1428,0.1428,0.1428,0.1428,0.5,0.5],
        'one_prob_bowl':[0.4285,0.4285,0.4285,0.4285,0.4285,0.4285,0.4285,0,0],
        'two_prob_bowl':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.5,0.5],
        'three_prob_bowl':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        'four_prob_bowl':[0.1428,0.1428,0.1428,0.1428,0.1428,0.1428,0.1428,0,0],
        'six_prob_bowl':[0.1428,0.1428,0.1428,0.1428,0.1428,0.1428,0.1428,0,0],
        'out_prob_bowl':[0.1428,0.1428,0.1428,0.1428,0.1428,0.1428,0.1428,0,0],
        'Outcome':[1, 0, 1, 'Wide', 'Out', 4, 1, 2, 0]
}
```

One issue is that with my original dataset there are over 600 unique names. I could manually .groupby each unique name in the batsman/bowler columns, but this is not a scaleable solution as new names will continually be added.

I am tempted to:-

1. .count the number of instances of each unique name for batsman/bowler;
2. .count the number of different outcomes for each unique batsman/bowler;
3. Perform a lookup to match the probability next to each batsman/bowler;

However, I am cautious about implementing a lookup function as detailed in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25935431/pandas-lookup-based-on-value) due to my dataset size which will continuously grow. In the past this has also created numerous issues when I have worked with excel/CSVs so I do not want to fall into any similar traps.

If someone could explain how they would go about solving this problem, so that I have something to aim towards, then it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much this scales with your actual dataset, but I find it hard to think of a better solution than using `groupby` on the `"Batsman"` column and then `value_counts` on the grouped `"Outcome"` column. Example:

```
data = {'Batsman':['Tom', 'Nick', 'Nick', 'Nick', 'Tom', 'Nick', 'Nick', 'Pete', 'Pete'],
            'Outcome':[1, 0, 1, 'Wide', 'Out', 4, 1, 2, 0],
            'Bowler':['Bill', 'Bill', 'Bill', 'Bill', 'Bill', 'Bill', 'Bill', 'Ben', 'Ben']
    }

grouped_data = df.groupby('Batsman')['Outcome'].value_counts(normalize=True)
print(grouped_data)
```

Output:

```
Batsman  Outcome
Nick     1          0.4
         0          0.2
         4          0.2
         Wide       0.2
Pete     0          0.5
         2          0.5
Tom      1          0.5
         Out        0.5
Name: Outcome, dtype: float64
```

Note that we did not need to groupby over each unique name manually, since `groupby` already does that for us.

The same logic can be applied to the `"Bowler"` column by simply replacing the `"Batsman"` string in the `groupby` call.

Comment: Thank you @jfaccioni. This looks to resolve the main problem i.e. attaining probabilities for each outcome. However, is it possible for the order of the original dataframe to be preserved? i.e. Tom, Nick, Nick etc. I thought that using groupby with sort=False this would be possible?

Also, is it actually possible for new columns i.e. zero_prob, one_prob to be added that identify the batsman/outcome and assign in the grouped_data values?

Answer (score 0):

I think this answers your question...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Batsman':['Tom', 'Nick', 'Nick', 'Nick', 'Tom', 'Nick', 'Nick', 'Pete', 'Pete'],
            'Outcome':[1, 0, 1, 'Wide', 'Out', 4, 1, 2, 0],
            'Bowler':['Bill', 'Bill', 'Bill', 'Bill', 'Bill', 'Bill', 'Bill', 'Ben', 'Ben']
    }
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
display(df)
batsman = df['Batsman'].unique()
bowler = df['Bowler'].unique()
print(sorted(batsman))
print(sorted(bowler))

final_df = pd.DataFrame()
for man in batsman:
    df1 = df[df['Batsman'] == man]
    count_man = len(df1)
    
    outcome = df['Outcome'].unique()
    count_outcome = len(outcome)
    
    batsman_prob = np.array(count_man/count_outcome)
    batsman_df = pd.DataFrame(data=[batman_prob], columns=[man], index=['Batsman'])
    
    final_df = pd.concat([final_df, batsman_df, ], axis=1)

for man in bowler:
    
    df1 = df[df['Bowler'] == man]
    count_man = len(df1)
    
    outcome = df['Outcome'].unique()
    count_outcome = len(outcome)
    
    bowler_prob = np.array(count_man/count_outcome)
    bowler_df = pd.DataFrame(data=[bowler_prob], columns=[man], index=['Bowler'])
    
    final_df = pd.concat([final_df, bowler_df, ], axis=1)
    
display(final_df)
```

Here is the output:

```
            Tom         Nick        Pete        Bill        Ben
Batsman     0.333333    0.333333    0.333333    NaN         NaN
Bowler      NaN         NaN         NaN         1.166667    0.333333
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. The above output tells me the probability of each being either a batsman or a bowler I believe (although I am not sure why Bill's value is > 1). 

The desired output is the 2nd dataframe from the question. There is useful code that I may be able to adapt to achieve this though, so thank you.