# Add Pandas Column with Row Lookup List

Tags: python, pandas, multipleselection

I want to add a column to a dataframe based on row contents. (The array is the result of `.melt`.) The selection column variables are in a list.

How can I form the selection programatically using the list?

```py
# cols = df.columns.tolist()[:3]
cols = ['height', 'weight', 'volume']

np.select([data.variable == 'height', data.variable == 'weight', data.variable == 'volume'], ['tall', '', 'bulky'], default='')
```

A string is easily formed but it is not the correct parameter type.

```py
np_cols = ['data.variable == \'' + c + '\'' for c in cols]
np_cols
# ["data.variable == 'height'", "data.variable == 'weight'", "data.variable == 'volume'"]
```

---

Full code shows extra column based on row selection:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['note', '', '', 'tall','','bulky'],
        ['TAE', 'B', 2020, 127, 338, 168],
        ['NQZ', 'A', 2020, 578, 85, 310],
        ['NQZ', 'Q', 2020, 196, 17, 10],
    ],
    columns=['airport', 'ver', 'year', 'height', 'weight', 'volume'],
)

index_cols = ['airport', 'ver', 'year']

original_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df[index_cols])
data = (
    df
    .melt(id_vars=original_index.names, var_name='variable', value_name='value')
    .set_index(index_cols)
    .loc[original_index]
    .reset_index(drop=False)
)

data = data[(data.airport != 'note')]
data['note'] = np.select([data.variable == 'height', data.variable == 'weight', data.variable == 'volume'], ['tall', '', 'bulky'], default='')

print(data)
```

Output:

```
   airport ver  year variable value   note
3      TAE   B  2020   height   127   tall
4      TAE   B  2020   weight   338
5      TAE   B  2020   volume   168  bulky
6      NQZ   A  2020   height   578   tall
7      NQZ   A  2020   weight    85
8      NQZ   A  2020   volume   310  bulky
9      NQZ   Q  2020   height   196   tall
10     NQZ   Q  2020   weight    17
11     NQZ   Q  2020   volume    10  bulky
```

Comment: What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: For what it's worth, this is a pandas question, not a numpy question.  You don't have a numpy array there.  All columns in a numpy array must be the same type.

Comment: You haven't told us what you WANT in that column.  What would it look like if you had solved your problem?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/25935431/4539999

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to the good people at https://www.pythondiscord.com/

Form a dictionary:

```
from_ = df.columns.tolist()[3:]
to_   = df.loc[df['airport'] == 'note'].values.flatten().tolist()[3:]
# from_ = ['height', 'weight', 'volume']
# to_   = ['tall', '', 'bulky']
data["note"] = data["variable"].map(dict(zip(from_, to_))).fillna("")
```

---

Shown in full code:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['note', '', '', 'tall','','bulky'],
        ['TAE', 'B', 2020, 127, 338, 168],
        ['NQZ', 'A', 2020, 578, 85, 310],
        ['NQZ', 'Q', 2020, 196, 17, 10],
    ],
    columns=['airport', 'ver', 'year', 'height', 'weight', 'volume'],
)

index_cols = ['airport', 'ver', 'year']

original_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df[index_cols])
data = (
    df
    .melt(id_vars=original_index.names, var_name='variable', value_name='value')
    .set_index(index_cols)
    .loc[original_index]
    .reset_index(drop=False)
)

data = data[(data.airport != 'note')]
# data['note'] = np.select([data.variable == 'height', data.variable == 'weight', data.variable == 'volume'], ['tall', '', 'bulky'], default='')

from_ = df.columns.tolist()[3:]
to_   = df.loc[df['airport'] == 'note'].values.flatten().tolist()[3:]
data["note"] = data["variable"].map(dict(zip(from_, to_))).fillna("")

print(data)
```

Output is identical:

```
   airport ver  year variable value   note
3      TAE   B  2020   height   127   tall
4      TAE   B  2020   weight   338
5      TAE   B  2020   volume   168  bulky
6      NQZ   A  2020   height   578   tall
7      NQZ   A  2020   weight    85
8      NQZ   A  2020   volume   310  bulky
9      NQZ   Q  2020   height   196   tall
10     NQZ   Q  2020   weight    17
11     NQZ   Q  2020   volume    10  bulky
```